# What's the difference between malloc and not using malloc when creating pointers to nodes of a linked list?

Tags: c, pointers, memory-management, linked-list

My linked list and nodes are defined as follows:

```
struct node{
int item;
struct node *next;
};

struct linkedlist{
    int size;
    struct node *head;
};

struct linkedlist *L=(struct linkedlist*)malloc(sizeof(struct linkedlist));
```

What's the difference between using:

```
struct node *temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp=L->head;
```

and:

```
struct node *temp=L->head;
```

(without using malloc)

Basically if i change anything to the temp pointer(e.g temp->item=3), will it be reflected in the original linked list L for both cases?

Thanks

Comment: The first one is pointless, you allocated some memory and then overwrote the only pointer to it.  Now it has been leaked.

Comment: The second one points temp to an uninitialized pointer.  Also pointless IMO.

Answer (score 2):

```
struct node *temp=malloc(sizeof(struct node));
temp=L->head;
```

In this case, you lose your reference to the memory block allocated by `malloc()` , and you **won't** be able to `free()` the allocated memory (*causing memory leak* ).

And it does not make sense as after allocating memory you change where the pointer points to .

Answer (score 2):

There's not much point in using malloc for the linked list structure, but it does make sense for the nodes.

```
struct linkedlist L = {0, NULL};         // L is empty list
struct node *temp
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));  // allocate a node
    temp->item = 2;
    temp->next = L.head;                 // insert it to start of list
    L.head = temp;
    L.size += 1;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));  // allocate another node
    temp->item = 1;
    temp->next = L.head;                 // insert it to start of list
    L.head = temp;
    L.size += 1;
    temp = malloc(sizeof(struct node));  // allocate another node
    temp->item = 0;
    temp->next = L.head;                 // insert it to start of list
    L.head = temp;
    L.size += 1;
```